# How to calculate the current flowing through a capacitor

Tags: capacitor

Let's say that there is capacitor set up in a circuit:

the capacitor's value : 1 F

the source : 20 V

How to calculate the current used by the capacitor , what equations should be used ?
[image]

Comment: Schematic? Resistance?

Comment: just a direct courent source

Comment: With ideal components, there will be an infinte current pulse of zero duration at the inistant the components are connected, then no current.  With real components, you will have to consider the internal resistance of the components, and the resistance of the wires, to determine the current.

Comment: thank you but in this case how can resolve this quetion, i am trying to learn how to find the courant so i can find the right resistor for a higher source voltage

Comment: You can't calculate the current flow from the given information.  If you place a resistor in series in the circuit, then you can calculate how much current will flow.  You can also calculate how long the capacitor will take to charge. The current will change as the capacitor charges.

Comment: You do realize that a 1F capacitor is enormous, right?

Comment: no i am just less than a beguiner with a bad english i am new asking for help

Comment: the goal from this is that i want to know what resistor to use for a capacitor the works with 11 v if i have a for example 220 v source energy

Comment: Here is a calculator that will let you play around with various voltage, resistance and capacitance values to start to get a feel for what happens.  https://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/fa/calculator/rc-circuit/

Comment: ok sir thak you i will see your link

Comment: You can't do what you want to. At least not how you want to.  May be you should explain why you want to charge an 11V capacitor from 220V.

Comment: You can't charge a capacitor using AC if that's your plan.

Comment: can i ask you why

Comment: AC changes direction continuously.  So, it charges, reverses, discharges, reverses, charges, repeat forever.

Comment: the main problem here is that i have a source of DC with 220v and a capacitor of working on 25 v and 0.03 mf i do not know what resistor to use to reduce the voltage coming from the source thoward the capacitor

Comment: You **cannot** do that with a series resistor.  What are you trying to do with the charged capacitor? And why 220VDC?

Comment: now i know that something like that can not hapned so what i need is not to find the right resistor to reduce the tension but to find the right battery , am i wrong

Comment: Why not just explain what you are trying to do?  You aren't charging the capacitor just for giggles.  What is the purpose behind charging the capacitor?

Comment: i swear god i am doing that  just for giggles , the teacher in my contry he told us about what can capacitors do and than i started asking my self these stupid lonitique question at the end i found my self locking touching the keyboard for answers on the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charge on a capacitor works with this formula: Q = C * V

To compute changes in that charge (we call this the current), take the derivative

dQ/dT = C * dV/dT + V * dC/dT

Now proclaim the capacitance to be a constant, and that simplifies to

dQ/dT = C * dV/dT = I (the current)

Suppose you are standing in dry cotton socks, largely air we shall assume, atop a concrete floor. You touch a 117VAC (160 volt Peak) 60Hz power wire. How much current flows through you, thru the socks, and into the concrete?

To compute this, we need "C" and "dV/dT"

First the C. Using C = E0 * Er * Area / Distance,

and assuming your feet are each 10cm by 30cm, the capacitance over the 1milliMeter of cotton+air insulation is

C ~~ 9e-12 Farad/meter * (Er=1) * (Area = 2 * 10cm * 30cm)/1mm

and to avoid being too precise with this approximation, round the 9e-12 up to 10e-12, and we now have

C = 10e-12 * 600 cm^2 / 0.1cm

C = 10e-12 Farad/meter * 6,000 cm

C = 10e-12 Farad/meter * 60 meter

C = 600e-12 Farad = 600 picoFarad between you and the concrete

Now we need the voltage SlewRate dV/dT

The voltage is 160 * sin (2 * pi * 60 * time) = 160*sin(377*time)

The derivative with respect to time is

160 * 377 *cosine (377*time), where our Peak SlewRate is 160 *377
or ~~ 60,000

Now compute I = C * dV/dT = 600e-12 * 60,000 or 0.6e-9 * 60e+3
and that you can do in your head

36e-6 = 36 microAmps of 60Hz current.